# Notepad++ Replace, RegEx

Tags: regex, macros, replace, notepad++

I'm trying to RegEx replace in Notepad++ and having issues.

Essentially I'm coding a script and have added an extra variable to a function which appears hundreds of time in my code.

So it was:
`MouseClick(442,421)`

Now I added a third variable for mouseclick delay so it will be

`MouseClick(442,421,4500)`

4.5 Sec is default delay

At the moment it won't work as a third variable isnt declared so I essentially want to use RegEx to find all my mouseclicks and add the default value of 4500 to the end, is it possible or is RegEx not the answer?

I'm trying to find: `MouseClick(*,*)`
And replace with: `MouseClick(*,*,4500)`

Also will the values be the same when replacing with a wildcard?

Thanks.

Comment: I would just edit the original function, add code that checks if the third argument is omitted using `arguments.length`, and if so assigns the default 4500 value.

Comment: Yah, I thought about that initially, thought RegEx could of been easier, but probably isn't :p I'm probably going to give that a whirl instead!

Comment: My thoughts on using regex to fix problems in a large code base: http://xkcd.com/1171/

Answer (score 3):

You can't replace with a wild card. You have to "capture" the values that were there before. You probably want to find

```
MouseClick\((.*),(.*)\)
```

and replace it with

```
MouseClick(\1,\2,4500)
```

Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: `.*` is a greedy match. If the line has two or more commas and a close bracket then the replace will not work as desired. Eg `MouseClick(442,421); // (x, y)` is changed to `MouseClick442,421); // (x, y,4500` using Notepad++ v6.2. (For some reason the replace loses the brackets, is that a Notepad++ bug?) Might be better to search for `(MouseClick\([ 0-9]*,[ 0-9]*)(\))` and replace with `\1,4500\2`.

Comment: Just found that round brackets specify grouping in Notepad++'s regular expression replace. Use `\(` and `\)` to insert round brackets. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html for more details.

Answer (score 1):

With the **Regular Expression** search mode selected, replace `MouseClick\((.*),(.*)\)` with `MouseClick(\1,\2,4500)`:

[image]